# Use getState to access key in redux state for API call

Tags: reactjs, axios, redux-thunk

I'm a little new to using thunk getState I have been even trying to console.log the method and get nothing. In state I see that loginReducer has they key property which I need to make API calls. `status(pin): true
key(pin): "Ls1d0QUIM-r6q1Nb1UsYvSzRoaOrABDdWojgZnDaQyM"`

Here I have a service:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import {thunk, getState} from 'redux-thunk'
import MapConfig from '../components/map/map-config'

const origin = 'https://us.k.com/'



class KService {

  getNorthAmericaTimes() {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
      const key = getState().key
      console.log('This is time key,', key)
      if (key) {
        dispatch(axios.get(`${origin}k51/api/datasets/k51_northamerica?key=${key}`))
      }
    }
    // const url = `${origin}k51/api/datasets/k51_northamerica?key=${urlKey}`
    // return axios.get(url)
  }
}

export default new K51Service()
```

However in my corresponding action I get that `Uncaught TypeError: _kService2.default.getNorthAmericaTimes(...).then is not a function`

This is what the action function looks like :

```
export function getKNorthAmericaTime(dispatch) {
  KService.getNorthAmericaTimes().then((response) => {
    const northAmericaTimes = response.data[0]
    dispatch({
      type: ActionTypes.SET_NORTH_AMERICA_TIMES,
      northAmericaTimes
    })
  })
}
```

I'm assuming it probably has to do with the if block not getting executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move your `axios.get()` method to your action creator and pass the promise to redux thunk, then when the promise is resolved dispatch the action with the response data so it can be processed by the reducer into the app's state.

**actions**

```
import axios from "axios";

export function fetchData() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const key = getState().key;
    const request = axios.get();// use your request code here
    request.then(({ response}) => {
      const northAmericaTimes = response.data[0]
      dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.SET_NORTH_AMERICA_TIMES, payload: northAmericaTimes});
    });
  };
}
```

Here's a very simple example of using axios with redux-thunk:

https://codesandbox.io/s/z9P0mwny

**EDIT**

Sorry, I totally forgot that you need to go to the state before making the request.

As you can see go to the state in your function, get the key from it, make the request and when the promise is resolved, dispatch the action with the response data. I've updated the live sample so you can see it working.

Again sorry...

Comment: I don't think that resolves the issue of making the get request with the right url I need to use getState().key and save that to a variable for the url.

Comment: I've updated the answer's code. Please check it again

Comment: Not a problem so I might be missing something I did comment out the original getKNorthAmericaTime(dispatch)  function then in home.js component I changed function name in mapDispatchToProps since I made the changes you suggested in the service function``` mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    getKNorthAmericaTime: () => getNorthAmericaTimes(dispatch),
  h),
 
  };
}``` let me know if you want me to put the home component up there as well. Thank you!

Comment: I presume that you have at least two action creators, one to get the login information and another to get the data using axios and the key. When the user is logged-in you can call the function to get the data from the server using `connect` from react-redux and then use redux-thunk to wait for the promise to be resolved. Als it'd be very useful if you could create a simple reduced sample in codesandbox in order to get a better look at your main component and your actions file.